# Different ways of suppressing 'uninitialized variable warnings' in C

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, initialization, clang

I have encountered multiple uses of the `uninitialized_var()` macro designed to get rid of warnings like:

```
warning: ‘ptr’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

For GCC ([`<linux/compiler-gcc.h>`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/compiler-gcc.h#L65)) it is defined such a way:

```
/*
 * A trick to suppress uninitialized variable warning without generating any
 * code
 */
#define uninitialized_var(x) x = x
```

But also I discovered that [`<linux/compiler-clang.h>`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/compiler-clang.h#L8) has the same macro defined in a different way:

```
#define uninitialized_var(x) x = *(&(x))
```

Why we have two different definitions? For what reason the first way may be insufficient? Is the first way insufficient just for Clang or in some other cases too?

---

[c](/questions/tagged/c) example:

```
#define uninitialized_var(x) x = x

struct some {
     int a;
     char b;
};

int main(void) {
     struct some *ptr;
     struct some *uninitialized_var(ptr2);

     if (1)
         printf("%d %d\n", ptr->a, ptr2->a); // warning about ptr, not ptr2
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209161/discussion-on-question-by-red0ct-different-ways-of-suppressing-uninitialized-va).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compilers are made to recognize certain constructs as indications that the author intended something deliberately, when the compiler would otherwise warn about it. For example, given `if (b = a)`, GCC and Clang both warn that an assignment is being used as a conditional, but they do not warn about `if ((b = a))` even though it is equivalent in terms of the C standard. This particular construct with extra parentheses has simply been set as a way to tell the compiler the author truly intends this code.

Similarly, `x = x` has been set as a way to tell GCC not to warn about `x` being uninitialized. There are times where a function may **appear** to have a code path in which an object is used without being initialized, but the author knows the function is intended not to be used with parameters that would ever cause that particular code path to be executed and, for reasons of efficiency, they want to silence the compiler warning rather than add an initialization that is not actually necessary for program correctness.

Clang was presumably designed not to recognize GCC’s idiom for this and needed a different method.

Answer (score -6):

> Why we have two different definitions?

Unclear, but I speculate that it's because Clang still produces a warning for `x = x` when `x` is uninitialized, but not for `x = *(&(x))`.  Under almost every circumstance<sup>*</sup> in which one of those expressions has well-defined behavior, the other has the same well-defined behavior.  Under other circumstances, such as when the value of `x` is undefined or indeterminate, both have undefined behavior, or the behavior of `x = x` is defined and that of `x = *(&(x))` undefined, so the latter provides no advantage.

> For what reason the first way may be insufficient?

Because the behavior of *both* is undefined in the use cases for which they seem to be intended.  It is not at all surprising, then, that different compilers handle them differently.

> Is the first way insufficient just for Clang or in some other cases too?

Both expressions' meaning and behavior is *undefined*.  In one sense, then, one cannot safely conclude that either is sufficient for anything.  In the empirical sense of whether using one or the other fools certain compilers into not emitting warnings that they otherwise would, and still *should*, emit, it is likely that there were, are, and / or will be compilers that handle the undefined behavior associated with both of those expressions differently than GCC and Clang do.

---

<sup>*</sup> The exception being when `x` is declared with `register` storage class, in which case the second expression has undefined behavior regardless of whether `x` has a well-defined value.

Comment: I cannot find specific documentation (because GCC is poorly documented), but the behavior of `x = x` is not truly undefined. It is not defined by the C standard, but GCC deliberately sets this as a method of telling the compiler that a warning that `x` **may** be used uninitialized is not wanted. In the absence of good documentation, we see evidence of this in [the documentation for `-Wuninitialized`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), which **intentionally** omits “self initialization”. There is a `-Winit-self` switch to alter this behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, "not defined by the C standard" is precisely what I mean by "undefined", and -- as you well know -- what we regulars generally mean by the term.  I do agree, however, that GCC *does not* document any (extension) semantics for self-initialization, so in that sense its behavior with GCC is still undefined. Furthermore, although I acknowledge that in practice,  GCC  distinguishes `-Winit-self`, I see no English-language reason to interpret the "used without first being initialized" of `-Wuninitialized` to somehow exclude the particular case of use for self-initialization.

Comment: As for the footnote, @EricPostpischil, the behavior of `*(&(x))` is undefined when `x` is declared with `register` storage class because the behavior of `&(x)` is undefined in that case (explicitly excluded from 6.5.3.2/1 and not otherwise defined).  Paragraph 6.3.2.1/2 is not required for that determination, nor does it conflict.

Comment: Re `&x` being undefined: Okay, your footnote is about the use of `&` with something that conceptually may not have an address. Since the subject was uninitialized things, it was unclear what you were referring to as the cause of not being defined.

Comment: Re English-language reason to exclude self-initialization: The documentation for `-Wuninitialized` says “If you want to warn about code that uses the uninitialized value of the variable in its own initializer, use the `-Winit-self` option.” So it is clear self-initialization is excluded. And, lest you think maybe `-Winit-self` is provided as some separate option, so that you could request a warning for self-initialization without requesting general warnings for uninitialized objects, the documentatio for `-Winit-self` says “Note this option can only be used with the `-Wuninitialized` option.”

Comment: Fair enough, @EricPostpischil, I accept that GCC's documentation effectively casts `-Winit-self` as a special and separately-diagnosed case of use of an uninitialized variable, thus allowing the user to instruct the compiler to suppress self-initialization warnings without suppressing warnings about other varieties of uninitialized use.  Presumably, then, the GCC developers believe that this is something that some users would want to do. But it does not follow from that that GCC in fact defines behavior for self-initialization.